# using global state and local state in some components using react, redux(thunk)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on an application which has several components.
Component A: Displays nodes of objects relations between them as edges.
I load data from an api using (redux-thunk based) by calling a function in Component As componentDidMount() function in the global state/store. 
Additionally I have to create the nodes based only of some fields of the objects stored in data.

Component B:
My intention is that  if a node is clicked  another component(detailed view of the node) is added to Component B. For this "detail view" I need other (additionall) fields of the objects.

My problem so far is that I need a local state of Component A also. The reason is that I also have to add temporary nodes which shouldn't be propagated to the global state/store.

So my questions are:
Can you give me an advice where I should select only the necessary fields of an Object in Component A and Component B?

How can I deal with the situation that I need a global state and a local state in Component B?

Comment: Consider providing a workable example that explains the relationship between these components. The problem will have better chances to be solved this way. There are use cases for local state with Redux but it's unclear why global state is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is create a store and subscribe to changes to changes of this store.

the next code use an example with redux.

```
// ./globalState.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const store = createStore(function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT':
    return state + 1;
  case 'DECREMENT':
    return state - 1;
  default:
    return state;
  }
});

export const useGlogalStore = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    return store.subscribe(() => setState(store.getState()));
  }, [store]);

  return [state, store.dispatch];
}
```

then in your app use only `useGlogalStore()` to read the state.

Example.

```
import { useGlogalStore } from './globalState.js';

export const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useGlogalStore();
  return <div>
    Count: {state}

    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}>Up</button>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}>Down</button>
  </div>
}
```